# array.forEach is displayed on console.log but not display on screen

Tags: reactjs, arrays, nested

```
const brands = [
  {
    id: 100,
    brand: "Digital Symphony",
    type: "Professional Services",
    projects: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "project 1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "project 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 101,
    brand: "Chiqui Don",
    type: "Food & Drinks",
    projects: [
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "project 4"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "project 5"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function findParentsProject(brands, id, parent = null) {
  for(let brand of brands){
    const result = brand.id === id ? parent
                : brand.projects && findParentsProject(brand.projects, id, brand);
    if (result) 
    {
      return (Object.values(result.projects)).forEach((project, id) =>{
        return(
            //console.log(project.id)
            <p key={id}>{project.id}</p>
        )
    })
      //return <p>aisyah</p>

    }
}
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>{findParentsProject(brands, 4)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this function is to find the parents project id. the result is in object then i convert to array. then i use forEach to loop through the array. why when i try to display the result it wont display on screen. but using console.log is working fine. this is my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-clarke-hbtkb2?file=/src/App.js:23-3278) for code reference.

Comment: try use map, insted of forEach.

Comment: if i use map then ill get this error ```SingleWork.jsx:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object```

Comment: It mean that data, you try to use in forEach/map, are not there, or didnt load yet. Try edit if statment like this (result && result.projects).

Comment: done, still same T.T

Comment: its complicated to help you when i dont even have your data. You need to console.log the data that are coming into the function, and make sure that Object.values(result.projects) is not null/undefined in the moment when you call it.